# Strange behaviour with Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, xcode4.3

I have a lot of classes on my project, my Source Editor displays the class names, iVar names ect correctly in all the class except one. In one of my classes all the input(mean, code) is displayed in white font and none of the class methods work. For example i have declared properties for `NSMutableArray` but i can't get the class method `objectAtIndex:`.. What can i do can anyone help please?

Comment: You've probably got a mistake somewhere in the code that is confusing the compiler. Can you include the code in your question?

Comment: the code is too long, it wil be boring i thing. in the other classes class names are displayed blue and variables are green.. but at this class everything is just white. How can i restart XCode can you please say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Menue->Product-Clean** and **clean your project**.
**Delete** your **app in simulator**, restart xcode,
restart operating system, check your project so you have no errors in your class,
and finally compile it again.

Sometimes i am getting this same behaviour, too. Dont know why.

Is the whole class without syntax highlighting? If no, check at the point where the syntax highlight ends, there could be a syntax error or something different.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your Xcode.It may be helpful

Comment: I restarted the computer but nothing changed.

Comment: in the other classes class names are displayed blue and variables are green.. but at this class everything is just white. How can i restart XCode can you please say that?

Answer (score 1):

There must be an error somewhere in your code. Unfortunately, sometimes xcode cannot show errors properly. As for me, somtimes I can't see errors at all. 
If restart don't work for you. Try **repairing permissions in Disk Utility** (that worked for me).